# Desempenho diferente usando limit menor que 100 e maior que 100

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma subselect que filtra 16 registros e nela existe um limit de 100.

Essa consulta resulta em um tempo normalmente de 1:20 ~ 1:40 minutos. Porém quando altero o limit para um numero maior que 100, seja 200, 300 ou 1k o resultado é retornado em menos de 1 segundo. O tempo é menor também quando uso limit menor ou igual a quantidade de registros disponíveis.

Realizei um EXPLAIN desse select e realmente existe uma mudança na forma em como o sistema realiza a pesquisa.

Gostaria de saber se há como otimizar essa pesquisa mantendo um limit baixo. O Mysql tem alguma configuração relacionado ao limit para causar essa diferença grande?

```
select consultas.id       
  from consultas                          
 where find_in_set(status,'Ok')
   and tipo_doc like '%qualquer%'
   and id_empresas in (6226,6416)
   and cnpj != '09966999000100'
   and case utilizado 
       when "S" then "Importado"  
       when "N" then "Pendente"
        end like '%Pendente%'  
 order by consultas.id desc                         
 limit 1000(ou 100)
```

Exemplo Explain com limit = 100
[image: Exemplo Explain com limit = 100]

Exemplo Explain com limit = 1k
[image: Exemplo Explain com limit = 1k]

Comment: Como está indexada essa tabela `consultas`?

Comment: Tenho a chave primaria no id, estrangeira no id_empresas e um index no cnpj.Olhando a documentação vi que pode ser algo relacionado ao limit juntamente com o order by, mas não entendi qual é a regra que rege qual busca ele vai usar. Quando adiciono um order by pelo numero do documento(Mais de um order) o problema se resolve, no explain posso ver que a regra de busca muda e o limit de 100 fica como o limit de 1k.

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi porque utilizar o case neste contexto,e outra dúvida por que usar **find_in_set(status,'Ok')** ao invés de **status like '%Ok%'**, mudando a query conforme abaixo melhora a performance?

```
select consultas.id       
  from consultas                          
 where status like '%Ok%'
   and tipo_doc like '%qualquer%'
   and id_empresas in (6226,6416)
   and cnpj != '09966999000100'
   and utilizado = 'N'
 order by consultas.id desc                         
 limit 1000(ou 100)
```

Comment: Faltou adaptar a Select para inserir aqui no S.O. Mas ela é assim porque recebe mais valores, é uma SQL bem dinâmica para filtrar documentos. Respondendo sua pergunta; não, não melhora, fiz testes usando o operador igual com o valor absoluto e também não resolve. O case é uma adaptação ruim para outros sistemas que enviam o valor inteiro "Pendente" ou "Importado" e o status pode conter outros 5 tipos.